# Normalisation of a spectra and display of data (matlab to python)

Tags: python, matlab, spectra

I have a spectra, the code was originally matlab and I have converted it to python.  There are 10 observations in this example, 29 orders.  It has been continuum normalised, however the plot looks very messy and I think it has something to do with the indexing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRQ1W.png). this is the matlab plot what it should look like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq4cM.jpg)  this is my python plot

This is the current code

```
import os
import numpy as np
import h5py
from scipy.io import loadmat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
%matplotlib widget

# Directory where the MATLAB files are located
directory = '/Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/Tau Ceti/'

# List all files in the directory matching the pattern '202*.mat'
file_list = [file for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.startswith('202') and file.endswith('.mat')]

# Initialize empty lists or arrays to store the data
ALLcalspec1 = []
ALLcalspec2 = []
ALLfib4spec = []
ALLfib4spec0 = []
ALLfib4specwave = []
ALLfib4specbNc = []
ALLfib4specerr = []
ALLfib4specS = []
ALLJD = []

# Loop through each .mat file and load the data
for s, mat_file in enumerate(file_list):
    data = loadmat(os.path.join(directory, mat_file))
    
    ALLcalspec1.append(data.get('calspec1', np.array([])))
    ALLcalspec2.append(data.get('calspec2', np.array([])))
    ALLfib4spec.append(data.get('fib4_spec', np.array([])))
    ALLfib4spec0.append(data.get('fib4_spec0', np.array([])))
    ALLfib4specwave.append(data.get('fib4_spec_wave', np.array([])))
    ALLfib4specbNc.append(data.get('fib4_spec_bNc', np.array([])))
    ALLfib4specerr.append(data.get('fib4_specerr', np.array([])))
    ALLfib4specS.append(data.get('fib4_specS', np.array([])))
    ALLJD.append(data.get('JD', np.array([])))

# Directory where the synthetic spectrum MATLAB file is located
synthetic_spectrum_file = '/Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/Tau Ceti/synth_teff4500_logg45.mat'

# Load the synthetic spectrum data using scipy's loadmat function
synthetic_spectrum_data = loadmat(synthetic_spectrum_file)

# Extract the relevant data from the loaded dictionary
synthetic_wavelengths = synthetic_spectrum_data.get('wavelength', np.array([]))
synthetic_intensities = synthetic_spectrum_data.get('intensity', np.array([]))

# Load the 'bcorr_fib4_all.mat' file using h5py
bcorr_file_path = '/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/Tau Ceti/bcorr_fib4_all.mat'

with h5py.File(bcorr_file_path, 'r') as bcorr_file:
    # List the available keys or group names in the file
    available_keys = list(bcorr_file.keys())

# Assuming you have already loaded ALLfib4spec as a NumPy array with shape (29, 10, num_files)
# Where 'num_files' is the number of data files you have

# Permute the dimensions to match the MATLAB code
permuted_ALLfib4spec = np.transpose(ALLfib4spec, (2, 1, 0))  # or np.swapaxes(ALLfib4spec, 0, 2)

# Extract the 15th order flux for all observations
order_15_flux = permuted_ALLfib4spec[14, :, :]  # 14 because Python uses 0-based indexing

# Calculate the median flux for order 15 across all observations
median_flux_order_15 = np.median(order_15_flux, axis=0)

# Define the threshold for a "bad" observation
threshold = 10000  # 10000 electrons in flux for order 15

# Create the 'bad' boolean mask
bad = median_flux_order_15 < threshold

# Create an index list of observations that are not bad
good_indices = [i for i, is_bad in enumerate(bad) if not is_bad]

# Filter the NumPy arrays based on the 'good_indices' list
ALLfib4spec = [ALLfib4spec[i] for i in good_indices]
ALLfib4spec0 = [ALLfib4spec0[i] for i in good_indices]
ALLfib4specbNc = [ALLfib4specbNc[i] for i in good_indices]
ALLfib4specerr = [ALLfib4specerr[i] for i in good_indices]
ALLfib4specwave = [ALLfib4specwave[i] for i in good_indices]
ALLJD = [ALLJD[i] for i in good_indices]
ALLcalspec1 = [ALLcalspec1[i] for i in good_indices]
ALLcalspec2 = [ALLcalspec2[i] for i in good_indices]

# Make a copy of ALLfib4specbNc to store continuum-corrected data
nALLfib4specbNc = ALLfib4specbNc.copy()

# Iterate through observations
for obs in range(len(nALLfib4specbNc)):
    print(f'obs: {obs + 1}', end=' ')
    
    # Iterate through orders
    for ord in range(len(nALLfib4specbNc[obs])):
        x = nALLfib4specbNc[obs][ord]
        tx = np.arange(len(x))
        
        # Fit a straight line (first-degree polynomial) to the data
        p = np.polyfit(tx, x, 1)
        
        # Calculate the continuum-corrected data
        xf = np.polyval(p, tx)
        nA = nALLfib4specbNc[obs][ord] / xf
        
        # Update nALLfib4specbNc with the continuum-corrected data
        nALLfib4specbNc[obs][ord] = nA
        
#Now nALLfib4specbNc contains the continuum-corrected data

# Convert nALLfib4specbNc to a NumPy array
nALLfib4specbNc = np.array(nALLfib4specbNc)

# Threshold values
upper_threshold = 1.2
lower_threshold = 0.01

# Apply upper and lower threshold to nALLfib4specbNc
nALLfib4specbNc = np.where(nALLfib4specbNc > upper_threshold, upper_threshold, nALLfib4specbNc)
nALLfib4specbNc = np.where(nALLfib4specbNc < lower_threshold, lower_threshold, nALLfib4specbNc)

# Save the data
prepared_data = {
    'nALLfib4specbNc': nALLfib4specbNc,
    'ALLcalspec1': ALLcalspec1,
    'ALLcalspec2': ALLcalspec2,
    'synthetic_wavelengths': synthetic_wavelengths,
    'synthetic_intensities': synthetic_intensities,
    'bcorr_fib4_all': bcorr_fib4_all
}

# Save the prepared data to a .mat file
savemat('Prepared.mat', prepared_data)

# Set the figure size (adjust these values as needed)
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))  # Adjust width and height as desired

# Iterate through observations
for obs in range(len(nALLfib4specbNc[0, 0, :])):  # Using the shape of nALLfib4specbNc to get the number of observations
    # Iterate through orders
    for ord in range(len(nALLfib4specbNc)):  # Using the shape of nALLfib4specbNc to get the number of orders
        
        # Extract the wavelength and spectrum data for the current observation and order
        wavelength_obs_ord = ALLfib4specwave[ord][:, obs]
        spectrum_obs_ord = nALLfib4specbNc[ord][:, obs]
        
        # Transpose the data to match MATLAB's behavior
        wavelength_obs_ord = wavelength_obs_ord.T
        spectrum_obs_ord = spectrum_obs_ord.T
        
        # Plot the order
        plt.plot(wavelength_obs_ord, spectrum_obs_ord, label=f'Order {ord + 1}')

# Add labels and title
plt.xlabel('Wavelength')
plt.ylabel('Spectrum')
plt.title('Spectrum after Normalization (All Observations and Orders)')
plt.grid(True)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: You might get slightly better plotting if you add `linestyle='.'` to `plt.plot(...)`. That will replace lines with one dot per data point. It would help to have some example data to see what structure it has.